# Printing PHP variable in form element in buildForm function

Tags: forms, 8

I have a php variable like this

```
$opensslOut = preg_replace('/\n\r{0,1}/', '<br>', $str);
```

I need to print its value on a form element. I used the following code

```
$form['openssl'] = [
      '#title' => t('OpenSSL'),
      '#markup' => t('$opensslOut'),
    ];
```

But didn't worked? I am a newbie in Drupal, Please help me to figure out a solution.

Comment: It seems, you are not only newbie in drupal, php as well as, Don't signle/dobule quotes for variables, It would handle as string :)

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers! This is a plain PHP question. If you need to pass to `t()` the content of `$opensslOut`, you simply use `t($opensslOut)`. Since Drupal doesn't change the PHP syntax, this question is off-topic for us. Also, notice that you don't pass to `t()` the content of a variable, since the first argument of `t()` needs to be a literal string.

Answer (score 2):

It's just a silly error `'#markup' => t('$opensslOut')` needs to be without the `''` because $opensslOut is a variable and not a string.

So use

`'#markup' => t($opensslOut)`

Answer (score 1):

The answer is simple.Just remove the quotes of $opensslOut.

$form['openssl'] = [
      '#title' => t('OpenSSL'),
      '#markup' => t($opensslOut),
    ];